# Changing background in UICollectionViewCell on didHighlightItemAt and didUnhighlightItemAt flashes while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to change background of cell in `UICollectionView` while user taps or focus on it. I want to give changing background feedback just after user taps, so I implemented this two methods in `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell {
        cell.highlight()
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell {
        cell.unhighlight()
    }
}
```

It works, but unfortunately when user scrolls on collection, the `didHighlightItemAt` method is called and immediately `didUnhighlightItemAt` method is called, so this results in flashing of cell.

I wonder about scheduling call of `cell.highlight` for 0.1 second and if `didUnhighlightItemAt` is called earlier than 0.1, I would cancel highlight call.

But are there any better solutions?

The similar effect occurs in Settings app (but it's harder to do that, in my app it's easier to see flashed cell):

[image: Demo]

Comment: it is because of cell re use , You have to manage highlighted state somewhere in your datasource array.

Comment: No, cell is still visible and it flashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor;
    return cell;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I'm using that also. The problem is that the didSelectItemAt is called when user raise finger, the didHighlightItemAt is called when user is touching cell. What I want is to distinguish scroll only. See Twitter app, they have implemented it correctly.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to find solution for this then.

Comment: I saw twitter app. You want `didHighlight` should not get called while scrolling. It should get called only when user taps on cell. If this is your requirement, then it's working for me. `didHighlight` is getting called only when user taps on cell and not while scrolling.

Comment: Not exactly. Test Twitter app by long tap on random cell, you will see that cell is changing background. If I use only didSelectItemAt, it will be called after you raise your finger.

Comment: Yes, This is what I'm saying I used `didHighlight` method and **on long press cell is getting highlighted** but not on scroll. So its working as you want and same as twitter implementation. I understood your problem so I'm not talking about `didSelect` methods.

Comment: Hmm, can you show more code? Maybe I'm doing something wrong, because when I leave the code only on didHighlight and didUnhighlight cell is changing on scrol...

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check it. I used `redColor` and `greenColor` just to distinguish cell highlight state.

Comment: I have the same logic, do you really don't have such behavior like in demo I showed? The background isn't changing very fast?

Answer (score -1):

What you're describing is the intended behavior. If you'd like to avoid this, use the cell.highlight() as you already are, but add a timer inside your cell as well which prevents it from un-highlighting.

You can add these methods to your cell to accomplish that. This will allow the cell to be naturally unhighlighted (as iOS intends) if the user releases the tap after two seconds, else it will remain highlighted for two seconds before going back.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    highlightTimer?.invalidate()
    unhighlight()
}

private var highlightTimer: Timer?
private var highlightDate: Date?
func highlight() {
    // Style your cell...

    highlightDate = Date()
    highlightTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 2.5, target: self, selector: #selector(unhighlight), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    highlightTimer?.fire()
}

@objc
func unhighlight() {
    if let highlightDate = highlightDate, abs(highlightDate.timeIntervalSinceNow) > 2.0 {
        // Un-style your cell...
    }
}
```

Another solution would be to animate the unhighlight changes so it isn't as harsh when scrolling. You can do this by just wrapping whatever you're doing in your unhighlight method inside a UIView.animate block

Comment: I've already mentioned it in comment, cell is not reused. I scroll the collectionview just a little bit (the cell is visible all the time) and didHighlightItemAt is called and then didUnhighlightItemAt immediatelly, but it shouldn't because it's swipe gesture, not tap.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish and hard to understand what you're doing wrong from the code posted here. You can implement a function in your cells to highlight them.

Comment: What you're describing is intended behavior. Updated question on how you can avoid it, but unless your app has a very special UI it's best to keep it as Apple ment it to work.

Comment: I think we still do understand each other. Notice that I don't want to highlight cell, because user is scrolling, not focusing on on cell. I want to prevent highlighting if the gesture is from scrolling, I thought maybe it's better approach than scheduling highlight and canceling it if didUnhighlightItemAt is called.

Answer (score -1):

Implement following two methods
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! TableCollectionViewCell
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! TableCollectionViewCell
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: That's what I'm doing in cell.highlight / unhighlight. See @MARTIN answer.